# Deploy Alfresco All-in-one multi-module to another installation

Tags: tomcat, deployment, alfresco

I have develop an All-in-one multi-module project using alfersco sdk. Ι want to install it in another alfresco community 5 installation. According to [this guide](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/tasks/alfresco-sdk-advanced-deploying-to-external-environments.html) I took the repo.war from all-in-one/repo/target rename it as alfresco.war and place it inside a different alfresco installation at tomcat/webapps but nothing changed none of module functionalities show up. Is this the correct way to install a multi-module project ?

Answer (score 0):

If you built the AIO project according to your reference, then the modules' AMPs should have been applied to the target wars.  Then following those directions should correctly apply the wars to the new Alfresco installation.

Be sure to follow this last step before restarting Tomcat:

> Note that we need to remove the exploded WAR directories for the new WARs to be picked up and deployed.

If you have done all of that, you can use [MMT](http://docs.alfresco.com/community5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-management-tool.html) to check for the existence of your modules.  Also check the alfresco and share logs upon startup for evidence of your modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use war instead use `.amp` files from `all-in-one/repo-amp/target` and `all-in-one/share-amp/target`. You will find amp in target folder with name `repo-amp.amp` and `share-amp.amp`

1. Stop tomcat
2. Copy `repo-amp.amp` to `Alfresco_HOME\amps`
3. Copy `share-amp.amp` to `Alfresco_HOME\amps_share`
4. Apply these amps (Assuming you are using windows system)

   Open cmd and go to `Alfresco_HOME/bin` and execute `C:\Alfresco\bin>apply_amps.bat -force`  remember to write `-force` with this, your custom code will override any files if you have used same name.
5. Start tomcat

Comment: it works but overwrites the appearance of my customized alfresco such as  background images theme etc. Is there any way to install amp without overwrite the custom appearance ?

Comment: I think you have misplaced your theme and images.. put your custom theme in `share-amp\src\main\amp\web\themes` and images accordingly.